# react-native create instance without rendering it

Tags: react-native, native-module

I'm working on a native module that accepts a "View" (finding the view in the viewregistry from it's reactTag/nodehandle). It all works fine if i include the view in the render function and finding the reactTag/nodehandle in the ref callback like so:

```
render(){
 return (<View ref={(ref)=>MyNativeModule.test(findeNodeHandle(ref))}><Text>foobar</Text></View>)
}
```

That works perfect and I can find the native view by looking up the tag I pass as the argument for my modules test function.

My question is: How can i instantiate a View (creating and getting a valid nodehandle?) without rendering it?

Hope you guys can help me.

/Mikkel

Comment: I don't think you can. The native backing view will only exists when the view is actually rendered and mounted. What are you actually trying to achieve? Can you perhaps work around by rendering the element offscreen (e.g. with position: absolute)?

Comment: my native module is setting the inputAccessoryView of a textinput. I need to create that view without rendering it. I can create a view by using UIManager.createView, but i don't know how i can get a View added to that view.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by making my native module create a RCTRootView and returned the reactTag back to javascript and then call

```
ReactNative.render(<Text>MY TEXT</Text>, reactTag)
```